# "E:target" not working in iframe?

Tags: css, google-chrome, target

**Fix this bug in Chrome 20.0.1115.1 dev-m**

---

I found a bug in chrome20.
Do you know anything about that?

http://jsdo.it/GeckoTang/x9Lo

HTML(http://jsdo.it/GeckoTang/x9Lo)

```
<iframe src="http://jsrun.it/GeckoTang/x9Lo"></iframe>
```

HTML(http://jsrun.it/GeckoTang/x9Lo)

```
<div id="hoge1">
<div id="hoge2">
    <a href="#hoge1">#hoge1</a>
    <a href="#hoge2">#hoge2</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hoge1:target {background:red;}
#hoge1:target [href$="#hoge1"]{font-weight:bold;}
#hoge2:target {background:gold;}
#hoge2:target [href$="#hoge2"]{font-weight:bold;}
```

- not working

  - chrome 20.0.1096.1 dev-m
  - 20.0.1104.0 canary
- working

  - Chrome 19.0.1084.24 beta (Mac)
  - Chrome18
  - IE9
  - Firefox11.0
  - Firefox3.6.12
  - Firefox10.0
  - Firefox Nightly13.0a
  - Safari5.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `name` in addition to `id` on the targets.

Comment: Interesting. I would mention that on the Chrome dev list. It might be intentional or not, but either way it is unexpected behaviour and should be brought up now while the software is still in dev.

Comment: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/113503 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84126